# VirtualBox is blocking my Internet port

Tags: networking, virtualbox, internet, vpn, proxy

I live in a dormitory where the Internet connection is through a proxy via Ethernet ports on the LAN.

After I install VirtualBox and install Kali Linux, my connection is automatically blocked by the server. When I asked the IT guy why that is, he told me that when the server detects two systems using the same port, it automatically blocks that port.

I hate this proxy because I cannot use the FileZilla extension. I have to pay for a VPN to use this programs and I don't like it.

How can I get this to work?

Comment: Just turn off the networking in Virtualbox, or disable the Virtual Ethernet adapter that is created by Virtualbox in your Network and Sharing options.

Comment: Thank you for advice but same time i need to use internet for bouth os system. i need it.

Comment: You should add that information to your original question then.

Answer (score 1):

It is very simple: before starting the VM, go to Network -> Adapter 1 -> Attached to, and you choose **NAT**. This means that your host will act as if it were a router, *i.e.*, it will MASQUERADE the fact that there are several pcs behind it. And you are now done. In line of principle, you can do this for as many pcs as you like.

Keep in mind just one thing: if you enable NAT, you will be unable to communicate between host and guest. To do that, enable a **second** adapter, choosing either host-only or Internal Network. The different between the two is that, if you have multiple VMs, with the first each VM can only talk to the host but not to the other guests, while in the second case all machines, virtual or not, will be able to talk to each other.